# Strange chkconfig behaviour on Debian for samba service

Tags: linux, debian, samba, chkconfig

The service "samba" is not starting at boot on this standard Debian 7.7 installation while it should.

Based on the chkconfig man page, I did this, but it still doesn't start at boot :

```
chkconfig samba 2345
```

If I compare to the ssh services it looks good :

```
chkconfig --list|grep "ssh\|samba "
samba                     0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
ssh                       0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
```

But something else looks strange (all services are "on", only samba is "2345") ?

```
# chkconfig |grep "ssh\|samba "
samba                   2345
ssh                     on
```

Then I tried something else :

```
# chkconfig samba on
```

But this is clearly worse :

```
# chkconfig --list|grep "ssh\|samba "
samba                     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
ssh                       0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
# chkconfig |grep "ssh\|samba "
samba                   off
ssh                     on
```

At this point I'm really confused, I tried to follow all manpages, forums and documentation and nothing the configuration is not behaving as expected. Am I missing some obvious point ?

Thanks a lot for any help !

P. S. In the above quotes, I'm always comparing to SSH because this service is working.

P. P. S. Update for the first comment, I also tried that :

```
# update-rc.d samba enable 2
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: error: no runlevel symlinks to modify, aborting!
```

Comment: The chkconfig utility isn't a native Debian tool. The first thing I would do is find out what the native tool is for managing services like this and use it.

Comment: @lain yes, but what is the native tool for this version ? I didn't find a clear answer to that...

Comment: # ls /etc/rc3.d/*samba
/etc/rc3.d/S05samba